# How to write IN and NOT IN using Apache Spark Dataframes

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have below 2 SQL query samples in SQL:

```
a) update DBTABLE1
    set col1 = 'Yes'
where ID IN ( '100' ) and City = any(select City from DBTable2 where Country = 'USA');

b) update DBTABLE1
    set col2 = 'No'
where ID NOT IN ( '100' ) and City = any(select City from DBTable2 where Country = 'USA');


How to write above 2 SQLs using Apache Spark Dataframes (Not Select subquery etc). A dataframe is already having these 2 columns - col1 and col2, I am changing their values using WITHCOLUMN and WHEN clause.
```

CitiDF contains dataset of number of cities.

```
I tried below but giving compile errors:

c) This is for (a) above:

withcolumn(col("col1"),when(col("id") === lit("100") 
and col("city").isin(CitiDF("city")), lit("yes")))

d) This is for (b) above:

withcolumn(col("col2"),when(col("id") === lit("100") 
and ! (col("city").isin(CitiDF("city"))), lit("yes")))
```

Comment: can you share the compile errors?

Answer (score 2):

To make things more concrete, let's consider some toy data.  We have one DataFrame named `df`, that looks like this:

```
+---+---------+------+------+
| id|     city|  col1|  col2|
+---+---------+------+------+
|100|Frankfurt|filler|filler|
|200|   Berlin|filler|filler|
|100|   Vienna|filler|filler|
|500| Victoria|filler|filler|
|600| Shanghai|filler|filler|
|100|  Cologne|filler|filler| 
+---+---------+------+------+
```

and another, named `cities`, that looks like this:

```
+---------+
| cityName|
+---------+
|Frankfurt|
|   Vienna|
+---------+
```

We can do your queries like this:

```
val cityList = cities.collect.map(x => x(0))
val df1 = df.withColumn("col1", when($"id" === "100" and $"city".isin(cityList: _*), "yes"))
```

The result we get is:

```
+---+---------+----+------+
| id|     city|col1|  col2|
+---+---------+----+------+
|100|Frankfurt| yes|filler|
|200|   Berlin|null|filler|
|100|   Vienna| yes|filler|
|500| Victoria|null|filler|
|600| Shanghai|null|filler|
|100|  Cologne|null|filler|
+---+---------+----+------+
```

For your second query, we use the same `cityList`:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("col2", when($"id" === "100" and !$"city".isin(cityList: _*), "yes"))
```

giving us

```
+---+---------+------+----+
| id|     city|  col1|col2|
+---+---------+------+----+
|100|Frankfurt|filler|null|
|200|   Berlin|filler|null|
|100|   Vienna|filler|null|
|500| Victoria|filler|null|
|600| Shanghai|filler|null|
|100|  Cologne|filler| yes|
+---+---------+------+----+
```

However, there is a big caveat to this approach.  If the number of cities is large, you could run out of memory by collecting all the names.  Instead, I would consider using an alternative approach, like an outer join:

```
df.join(cities, df("city") === cities("cityName"), "outer").
  withColumn("col1", when($"cityName".isNotNull and $"id" === "100", "yes")).
  withColumn("col2", when($"cityName".isNull and $"id" === "100", "yes")).
  drop("cityName")
```

giving us

```
+---+---------+----+----+
| id|     city|col1|col2|
+---+---------+----+----+
|100|Frankfurt| yes|null|
|500| Victoria|null|null|
|200|   Berlin|null|null|
|100|   Vienna| yes|null|
|100|  Cologne|null| yes|
|600| Shanghai|null|null|
+---+---------+----+----+
```

Yes, it introduces an extra column, but only temporarily, and avoids the pulling the potentially large list of cities into the driver's memory.

Comment: Thanks Jason. This is what I had done but it failed, looks like I missed some arguments :)

Comment: Want to translate below:   

  update TABLE1
    set Col1 = 'HEY'
    where Col2 = any(select Col2 from TABLE2 where Col3 = 'YES'), how to do this using above way ?

Comment: Wrote it as below, pls see if this is right: 

df1.join(cities, df1.col("city").cast("string").contains(cities.col("cityName").cast("string"))
 .withColumn("col1", when($"Col2" === "HEY", "Yes"))

Comment: Yes, there were two issues I could see in your original code: 1) `withColumn` expects a `String` (like `"col1"`) as its first argument, not a `Column` (like `col("col1")`.  2) `isin` does not expect a `Column`, but a list of values.

Answer (score 2):

With the sample data as Jason used and without mixing lists outside, the solution can be achieved using spark-sql itself. Check this out:

```
val df = Seq((100,"Frankfurt","filler","filler"),(200,"Berlin","filler","filler"),(100,"Vienna","filler","filler"),(500,"Victoria","filler","filler"),(600,"Shanghai","filler","filler"),(100,"Cologne","filler","filler")).toDF("id","city","col1","col2")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("city_details")
val city = Seq(("Frankfurt"),("Vienna")).toDF("cityName")
city.createOrReplaceTempView("city_list")
df.show(false)
spark.sql(
  """ select id,city, case when id=100 and array_contains((select collect_list(cityname) from city_list), city) then 'yes' else null end as col1,
      case when id=100 and not array_contains((select collect_list(cityname) from city_list), city) then 'yes' else null end as col2
      from city_details
  """).show(false)
```

Output:

```
+---+---------+----+----+
|id |city     |col1|col2|
+---+---------+----+----+
|100|Frankfurt|yes |null|
|200|Berlin   |null|null|
|100|Vienna   |yes |null|
|500|Victoria |null|null|
|600|Shanghai |null|null|
|100|Cologne  |null|yes |
+---+---------+----+----+
```

Comment: Thanks for ur help, but I wanted using dataframes rather than using spark-sql. Thanks again.